# Deploy Comfy to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I really need help here please.

I made a rails application with the default gemfile and then followed the instructions for installation in comfy's wiki. Ran my app in the local host with webrick and sqlite3 getting no issues really, even though I am learning as I develop, but when the app was kind of ready (I judge it so it probably wasn't) for getting it up and running on heroku it failed, I checked the logs I migrated the database and tried with new apps, even tried installing psql and using unicorn as a web server (tried is emphasized cause neither of em worked for various reasons).

I've spent 6 hours (more or less) going through wikis and stuff but there really isn't much material for this CMS, please help, I even created a stack overflow account because of this issue.

I need a more detailed guide of the configuration needed for heroku.

And I have another question, what happens to the info generated by the users in heroku, how can I backup that. If I push something the differences in the cloud get erased? (Obviously the answer is no, but I want to know how and why)

Thanks a lot, this is driving me crazy.

FYI I'm an amateur.

Pd I can post some of my code's app if required.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information on what is going wrong - this question is not answerable as it stands. Also this isn't a forum - 2 unrelated questions (how do I setup comfortable Mexican sofa / how do I backup heroku data) don't belong in the same question

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what information should I provide? (I'll post another question for the heroku issue later or just google it)

Comment: Well you could start with what error(s) you are getting & what triggers them. If it's not an error then describe how actual behaviour is differing from expected behaviour